# How to figure out what's been jitted at warmup?

Tags: asp.net, .net, profiling, jit, dottrace

.NET applications, especially ASP.NET applications, can have an annoyingly long warmup time in part due to jitting.

I recently tried dottrace to profile such a warmup and it tells me how much time indeed goes to jitting. Now I wonder:

How can I tell *what's* been jitted?

I want to know because not all code is created equal and there maybe be toolkits I can replace with others that compile faster or more fine-grained.

Answer (score 1):

In the TimeLine mode, you can filter all the jit events